# Oracle - PLS-00103: Trigger - End of file error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created the above trigger but its giving me error:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;   The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue

Trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
subView_insert_tr INSTEAD OF INSERT ON VSubscriber
DECLARE
 lendings           Lending_tab ;
 i                  INTEGER ;
 copy_book_var      Copy_list_T;
 copy_book_vartemp  REF Copy_list_T ;

BEGIN
  lendings := :NEW.Lending_List;
  INSERT INTO Subscriber (num_s, name) VALUES (:NEW.num_s, :NEW.name) ;
  FOR i IN 1..lendings.COUNT LOOP
   copy_book_vartemp := lendings(i).Copy_Book_REF;
   SELECT DEREF(copy_book_vartemp) INTO copy_book_var FROM DUAL ;

INSERT INTO LENDING (num_s, num_c) VALUES (
     :NEW.num_s, copy_book_var.num_c,
     lendings(i).d_L) ;
 END LOOP ;

END ;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with this insert

```
INSERT INTO LENDING (num_s, num_c) VALUES (
     :NEW.num_s, copy_book_var.num_c,lendings(i).d_L) ;
```

Modified that, and try with this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
subView_insert_tr INSTEAD OF INSERT ON VSubscriber
DECLARE
 lendings           Lending_tab ;
 i                  INTEGER ;
 copy_book_var      Copy_list_T;
 copy_book_vartemp  REF Copy_list_T ;

BEGIN
  lendings := :NEW.Lending_List;
  INSERT INTO Subscriber (num_s, name) VALUES (:NEW.num_s, :NEW.name) ;
  FOR i IN 1..lendings.COUNT LOOP
   copy_book_vartemp := lendings(i).Copy_Book_REF;
   SELECT DEREF(copy_book_vartemp) INTO copy_book_var FROM DUAL ;

INSERT INTO LENDING (num_s, num_c) VALUES (
     :NEW.num_s, copy_book_var.num_c);
  --   lendings(i).d_L) ;
 END LOOP ;

END ;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Dileep, I changed the line of code to:                    INSERT INTO LENDING (num_s, num_c, d_L) VALUES (
     :NEW.num_s, copy_book_var.num_c, lendings(i).d_L) ;            but the problem is still there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @EffiongCharles Can you format the code in Toad, so that you 'll get to know the syntactical errors. that 'll help us to execute the trigger.